# How to use Beam Search for HuggingFace Library?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am using HuggingFace library for BART model. I want to use Beam Search for text generation in interface time.

I know there is `model.generate` to use beam search.

But in my case, I am using the BART encoder and decoder in a variational autoencoder.
As there are latent variables inside the autoencoder, I am not directly using the model.

In short,

```
enc = bart.encoder(input)
latent_var = some_linear_layers(enc)
output = bart.decoder(latent_var)
```

Is there any built-in way to use beam search in my case? Or any well-known library, which will generate the beam search given input and model?